# How to make Spoq generate high-level specifications in Coq (not just AST) for the functions in LLVM IR

Tags: c, coq, llvm-ir, formal-verification, formal-methods

I am trying to use [Spoq](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/osdi23-li-xupeng.pdf) framework (and on [GitHub](https://github.com/columbia/osdi23-paper114-ae)) to translate code from C to Coq.
I faced problem - I am getting only low-level specifications for my functions (just AST), but I want to get high-level specifications (functions with parameters, fixpoints...).

I successfully compiled my C code to LLVM IR, and managed to create Coq project with

```
python3 AutoV/main.py build TestFactorialProof/proof.v
```

Obviously my configuration file proof.v is not good enough. I should manually write definitions for each fixpoint, like this

```
Definition rank (i: nat) := MAX_PAGE - i.(*user input*)
```

but where exactly should I write them? in the configuration (proof.v) file?

Couldn't find any documentation for Spoq with simple demonstrative examples.

This is my simple C code which I desire to translate to Coq

```
int factorial (int a); 
void epow(int *, int);
int hello();

int main()    
  {    
    factorial(5);
    
    int x = 34, y = 6;
    epow(&x, 3);
    epow(&y, 1);
    
    hello();
    hello();
    hello();
    
    return 0;  
  }   
  
int factorial (int a) {
    int i, fact=1;
    for (i = 1; i <= a; i++) {
      fact=fact*i;
    }
    return fact;
    hello();
}

void epow(int *base, int pow) {
    while (pow > 0) {
        *base = *base * 10;
        pow--;
    }
}

int hello () {
    static int count = 1;
    return count++;
}
```

and this is my configuration file proof.v

```
Definition PROJ_NAME: string := "TestFactorial".
Definition PROJ_BASE: string := "./ProofGen".

(* Include "datatypes.v". *)
(* Include "constant.v". *)
(* Include "load_store.v". *)

Section Bottom.

  Definition LAYER_DATA := RData.
  Definition LAYER_CODE: string := "./factorial.json".
  (* Definition LAYER_LOAD: string := "load_RData". *)
  (* Definition LAYER_STORE: string := "store_RData". *)
  (* Definition LAYER_GET_REG: string := "get_reg_RData". *)
  (* Definition LAYER_SET_REG: string := "set_reg_RData". *)
  Definition LAYER_PRIMS: list string := 
      "epow" :: "hello" :: "factorial" :: nil.

End Bottom.

Section InlineAsms.

  Definition LAYER_DATA := RData.
  Definition LAYER_CODE: string := "./factorial.json".
  (* Definition LAYER_LOAD: string := "load_RData". *)
  (* Definition LAYER_STORE: string := "store_RData". *)
  (* Definition LAYER_GET_REG: string := "get_reg_RData". *)
  (* Definition LAYER_SET_REG: string := "set_reg_RData". *)
  Definition LAYER_PRIMS: list string :=
    nil.

End InlineAsms.
```

in file Code.v I am having AST

```
Require Import String.
Require Import ZArith.
Require Import List.
Require Import LayerSem.Libs.SMap.
Require Import LayerSem.IR.
Require Import LayerSem.IRSem.
Require Import LayerSem.Asm.AsmInsn.

Local Open Scope Z_scope.
Local Open Scope string_scope.

(************ Structures ************)

Definition structures :  list (string * typ) :=
    nil.

(************ Global Variables ************)

Definition v_hello_count :=
    {| vname := "hello.count";
       vtype := (TInt TI32);
       vconst := false;
       vinitializer := (Some (VInt (1)));
       valign := 4 |}.

Definition globvars : list (string * global_var) :=
    (("hello.count", v_hello_count)
     :: nil).

(************ Functions ************)

Definition f_factorial :=
    {| fname := "factorial";
       rettype := (TInt TI32);
       fargs :=
        (("v_0", (TInt TI32))
         :: nil);
       falloca_vars := ("v_4" :: "v_2" :: "v_3" :: nil);
       fbody := 
        (Some 
            ((IAlloca (TPtr (TInt TI32)) "v_2" 4)
             :: (IAlloca (TPtr (TInt TI32)) "v_3" 4)
             :: (IAlloca (TPtr (TInt TI32)) "v_4" 4)
             :: (IStore (TInt TI32) (VLocal "v_2") (VLocal "v_0") 4)
             :: (IStore (TInt TI32) (VLocal "v_4") (VInt (1)) 4)
             :: (IStore (TInt TI32) (VLocal "v_3") (VInt (1)) 4)
             :: (ILoop
                   ((ILoad (TInt TI32) "v_6" (VLocal "v_3") 4)
                    :: (ILoad (TInt TI32) "v_7" (VLocal "v_2") 4)
                    :: (IBinOp TBool "v_8" Csle (VLocal "v_6") (VLocal "v_7"))
                    :: (IIf (VLocal "v_8")
                        ((ILoad (TInt TI32) "v_10" (VLocal "v_4") 4)
                         :: (ILoad (TInt TI32) "v_11" (VLocal "v_3") 4)
                         :: (IBinOp (TInt TI32) "v_12" OMul (VLocal "v_10") (VLocal "v_11"))
                         :: (IStore (TInt TI32) (VLocal "v_4") (VLocal "v_12") 4)
                         :: (ILoad (TInt TI32) "v_14" (VLocal "v_3") 4)
                         :: (IBinOp (TInt TI32) "v_15" OAdd (VLocal "v_14") (VInt (1)))
                         :: (IStore (TInt TI32) (VLocal "v_3") (VLocal "v_15") 4)
                         :: nil)
                        ((ILoad (TInt TI32) "v_17" (VLocal "v_4") 4)
                         :: (IReturn (TInt TI32) (Some (VLocal "v_17")))
                         :: nil))
                    :: IContinue
                    :: nil))
             :: nil)) |}.

Definition f_main :=
    {| fname := "main";
       rettype := (TInt TI32);
       fargs :=
        nil;
       falloca_vars := ("v_1" :: "v_2" :: "v_3" :: nil);
       fbody := 
        (Some 
            ((IAlloca (TPtr (TInt TI32)) "v_1" 4)
             :: (IAlloca (TPtr (TInt TI32)) "v_2" 4)
             :: (IAlloca (TPtr (TInt TI32)) "v_3" 4)
             :: (IStore (TInt TI32) (VLocal "v_1") (VInt (0)) 4)
             :: (ICall (TInt TI32) (Some "v_4") (VGlobal "factorial") [(VInt (5))])
             :: (IStore (TInt TI32) (VLocal "v_2") (VInt (34)) 4)
             :: (IStore (TInt TI32) (VLocal "v_3") (VInt (6)) 4)
             :: (ICall TVoid None (VGlobal "epow") [(VLocal "v_2"); (VInt (3))])
             :: (ICall TVoid None (VGlobal "epow") [(VLocal "v_3"); (VInt (1))])
             :: (ICall (TInt TI32) (Some "v_5") (VGlobal "hello") [ ])
             :: (ICall (TInt TI32) (Some "v_6") (VGlobal "hello") [ ])
             :: (ICall (TInt TI32) (Some "v_7") (VGlobal "hello") [ ])
             :: (IReturn (TInt TI32) (Some (VInt (0))))
             :: nil)) |}.

Definition f_hello :=
    {| fname := "hello";
       rettype := (TInt TI32);
       fargs :=
        nil;
       falloca_vars := nil;
       fbody := 
        (Some 
            ((ILoad (TInt TI32) "v_1" (VGlobal "hello.count") 4)
             :: (IBinOp (TInt TI32) "v_2" OAdd (VLocal "v_1") (VInt (1)))
             :: (IStore (TInt TI32) (VGlobal "hello.count") (VLocal "v_2") 4)
             :: (IReturn (TInt TI32) (Some (VLocal "v_1")))
             :: nil)) |}.

Definition f_epow :=
    {| fname := "epow";
       rettype := TVoid;
       fargs :=
        (("v_0", (TPtr (TInt TI32)))
         :: ("v_1", (TInt TI32))
         :: nil);
       falloca_vars := ("v_4" :: "v_3" :: nil);
       fbody := 
        (Some 
            ((IAlloca (TPtr (TPtr (TInt TI32))) "v_3" 8)
             :: (IAlloca (TPtr (TInt TI32)) "v_4" 4)
             :: (IStore (TPtr (TInt TI32)) (VLocal "v_3") (VLocal "v_0") 8)
             :: (IStore (TInt TI32) (VLocal "v_4") (VLocal "v_1") 4)
             :: (ILoop
                   ((ILoad (TInt TI32) "v_6" (VLocal "v_4") 4)
                    :: (IBinOp TBool "v_7" Csgt (VLocal "v_6") (VInt (0)))
                    :: (IIf (VLocal "v_7")
                        ((ILoad (TPtr (TInt TI32)) "v_9" (VLocal "v_3") 8)
                         :: (ILoad (TInt TI32) "v_10" (VLocal "v_9") 4)
                         :: (IBinOp (TInt TI32) "v_11" OMul (VLocal "v_10") (VInt (10)))
                         :: (ILoad (TPtr (TInt TI32)) "v_12" (VLocal "v_3") 8)
                         :: (IStore (TInt TI32) (VLocal "v_12") (VLocal "v_11") 4)
                         :: (ILoad (TInt TI32) "v_13" (VLocal "v_4") 4)
                         :: (IBinOp (TInt TI32) "v_14" OAdd (VLocal "v_13") (VInt (-1)))
                         :: (IStore (TInt TI32) (VLocal "v_4") (VLocal "v_14") 4)
                         :: nil)
                        ((IReturn TVoid None)
                         :: nil))
                    :: IContinue
                    :: nil))
             :: nil)) |}.

Definition funcs :=
    (("factorial", f_factorial)
     :: ("main", f_main)
     :: ("hello", f_hello)
     :: ("epow", f_epow)
     :: nil).

(************ AsmProcs ************)

Definition asm_procs :=
    nil.

(************ IR Module ************)

Definition code :=
  {| structs := structures;
     global_vars := globvars;
     functions := funcs;
     asm_procedures := asm_procs |}.
```

and /LAYER_NAME/Spec.v
-- is not giving me any high-level specifications of the functions
(auto-generated)
just this

```
Require Import CommonDeps.
Require Import DataTypes.
Require Import GlobalDefs.

Local Open Scope string_scope.
Local Open Scope Z_scope.

Section InlineAsms_Spec.

  Context `{int_ptr: IntPtrCast}.

End InlineAsms_Spec.
```

Thank you!